# How can I add n days to a date but exclude Sundays using yyyymmdd format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want a date after 'n' days from a given date in 'yyyymmdd' format (output is also in same format).Adding n days should exclude Sundays. Is it possible to do this in javascript?

Here is my code to add n days to a date

```
    function mydate(dateStr,offset) 
    {
       var ymd = dateStr.match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
       if (ymd) 
       {
         var date = new Date(ymd[1], ymd[2] - 1, ymd[3]);
         date.setDate(date.getDate() + offset);
         return $.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', date);
       } 
       else 
       {  // parse error
         return null;
       }
    }
```

for example,

```
    mydate('19890831',10)
```

will return

```
    19890910
```

but actually what I need is '19891012' because there are 2 Sundays when we add 10 days to the '19890831'

Comment: Look into [datejs.com](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: First thing you'll need to work out is how many Sundays there are. date.js (http://www.datejs.com/) is pretty good at handling dates.

Comment: Two libraries to suggest: http://datejs.com/ and http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I just want to do this without any other external library

Comment: Is there any function like AddBusinessDays() of c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution; you can just loop through the days and skip sundays:

```
while (offset > 0) {      
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  if (date.getDay() != 0) offset--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to answer here to figure out how many sundays are there between two dates once you have that you can simply add that number to your original days diff.

[How to determine number Saturdays and Sundays comes between two dates in java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210906/how-to-determine-number-saturdays-and-sundays-comes-between-two-dates-in-java-sc)

Answer (score 0):

```
function pad(n){
    if(n < 10){
        return "0" + n;
    }
    return n;
}

function addDays(dt, n){
    var matches = dt.match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
    var year = matches[1];
    var month = matches[2];
    var day = matches[3];

    var dt = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    var weekDay = dt.getDay();

    if((weekDay + n) > 6){
        n = n + 1;
    }

    if(weekDay === 0){
        n = n + 1;
    }

    var oneDayInMillis = 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var newDt = new Date(dt.getTime() + (oneDayInMillis * n));

    return "" + newDt.getFullYear() + pad(newDt.getMonth() + 1) + pad(newDt.getDate());
}
```