# get number of sundays in a month using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine number Saturdays and Sundays comes between two dates in java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210906/how-to-determine-number-saturdays-and-sundays-comes-between-two-dates-in-java-sc)

I want to find the no of Sundays in a month using javascript

i am passing month and year to a function

i am able to calculate total days using

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function daysInMonth(month, year) {
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        }
    </script>
```

but need to find no of sundays

Please suggest

Comment: Start with [How to determine number of Saturdays and Sundays between two dates in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210906/how-to-determine-number-saturdays-and-sundays-comes-between-two-dates-in-java-sc).

Comment: Learn the javasrcript Date function http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: Answer is here http://jsfiddle.net/93L8onrq/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```js
function sundays(year, month) {

    var day, counter, date;

    day = 1;
    counter = 0;
    date = new Date(year, month, day);
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        if (date.getDay() === 0) { // Sun=0, Mon=1, Tue=2, etc.
            counter += 1;
        }
        day += 1;
        date = new Date(year, month, day);
    }
    return counter;
}

console.log(sundays(2012, 5));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... `sundays(2012, 12)` returns `0`. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/zkk2D/

Comment: 0 stands for January, 11 stands for December.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sundaysInMonth( m, y ) {
  var days = new Date( y,m,0 ).getDate();
  var sundays = [ (8 - (new Date( m +'/01/'+ y ).getDay())) % 7 ];
  for ( var i = sundays[0] + 7; i < days; i += 7 ) {
    sundays.push( i );
  }
  return sundays;
}

alert( sundaysInMonth( 10,2012 ) ); //=> [ 7,14,21,28 ]
alert( sundaysInMonth( 10,2012 ).length ); //=> 4
```

Comment: it fail when i use 12 as month 2023 as year