# How to print specific day's date in month using jquery or php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

For example, I select March 2013 month and I want to print the all dates of Sunday in this month. How can I print a specific day's date in month using jquery or php?

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
var day = new Date();
var month = day.getMonth() + 1;
var date = day.getDate() + '-' + month + '-' + day.getFullYear();
jQuery("#datepicker").val(da`enter code here`te);
});
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106961/get-number-of-sundays-in-a-month-using-javascript/13107035#13107035

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would find the first weekday of the month, and then find the first Sunday from that, then increment by 7 to find the rest of the Sundays.

An example in PHP:

```
$start = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d. m. Y', '01. 03. 2013');
$end = clone $start;
$end->add(new \DateInterval('P1M'));

// output all sundays between $start and $end
$periodInterval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('first sunday');
$periodIterator = new \DatePeriod($start, $periodInterval, $end, \DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

foreach ($periodIterator as $date) {
    // output each date in the period
    echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully know what you mean, does this do what you want?

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var date= new Date();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var tmp;
var day = 1000 * 3600 * 24;
while(true) {
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + day);
    tmp = date.getMonth() + 1;
    if(tmp!= month) {
        break;
    }    
    if(date.getDay() == 0)
        document.write(date+"</br>");        
}
```

see it work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7HQUH/)
​

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are using datepicker you may try to check every last box in the table, shown as calendar. It is gonna be the way when u will be sure that you have same data in javascript/php and on the screen