# total number of sundays in a month

Tags: javascript

I am using following code to determine total number of sundays in a month, however it gives incorrect result

```
function sundaysInMonth(start) {
        var dat = new Date('1 ' + start);
        var y = dat.getFullYear();
        var m = dat.getMonth() + 1;
        var days = new Date( y,m,0 ).getDate();
        var sundays = [ 8 - (new Date( m + '/01/' + y ).getDay()) ];
        for ( var i = sundays[0] + 7; i < days; i += 7 ) {
            sundays.push( i );
        }
        return sundays.length;
    }
```

When I call above functions like `console.log(sundaysInMonth('September 2013'));` then it returns `4` whereas `September 2013` has 5 sundays.

I am getting above code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106961/get-number-of-sundays-in-a-month-using-javascript)

Comment: when you step through your code in the developer tools debugger, which line has the first error?

Comment: There is no error. It just returns incorrect result.

Comment: Start with some obvious debugging. For example, is the variable `days` initialized with the correct number? And why are you starting the 8th of any month? Days are counted 0..6.

Comment: days variable is fine. Nothing wrong there. I already debugged it but could not find why the result is wrong. I suspect thats the variable `sundays`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine number Saturdays and Sundays comes between two dates in java script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210906/how-to-determine-number-saturdays-and-sundays-comes-between-two-dates-in-java-sc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loops are not needed for this calculation.

```
function sundaysInMonth(start) {
    var d = new Date('1 ' + start); // May not parse in all browsers
    var ndays = new Date( d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 0 ).getDate();
    return Math.floor((ndays + (d.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
}
```

Test for all months in 2013: http://jsfiddle.net/rGN28/2/

Answer (score 3):

Aw, Matt beat me by one minute! I came up with basically the same solution, only with more comments. ;)

```
function sundaysInMonth(sMonthAndYear) {

// Get the year and month as integers
    var dDate = new Date('1 ' + sMonthAndYear);
    var y = dDate.getFullYear();
    var m = dDate.getMonth() + 1;

// Get the number of days in the month
    var iDayCount = new Date( y,m,0 ).getDate();

// Find the first Sunday
    var iFirstSunday = (8 - dDate.getDay());
    if (iFirstSunday > 7) {iFirstSunday = 1};

// Calculate the total number of Sundays in the month
    var iSundayCount = Math.ceil ((iDayCount + 1 - iFirstSunday) / 7);

// Return the count
    return iSundayCount;

}
```

Comment: +1 Anyway :) confirmed this works correctly for all months in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I just fixed issue in your code

```
function sundaysInMonth(start) {
        var dat = new Date('1 ' + start);
        var y = dat.getFullYear();
        var m = dat.getMonth() + 1;
        var days = new Date( y,m,0 ).getDate();
        var sundays = [ (8 - (new Date( m + '/01/' + y ).getDay())) % 7 ];

        for ( var i = sundays[0] + 7; i < days; i += 7 ) {
            sundays.push( i );

        }
        return sundays.length;

    }
```

In array variable `sundays` we need to intially store the first day value which is a sunday. There was a small bug for months with Day 1 is sunday. For example as in your question `September 2013`
For these months your code will store `8` instead of `1` `sundays` array as first sunday. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old but here is my attempt to find number of Sundays in a month if anyone needs help.

```
<?php

$year = 2020; // Year to check
$month = 1; // Month to check (1-12)

// Get the first and last day of the month as timestamps
$firstDay = strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
$lastDay = strtotime("+1 month", $firstDay);

// Initialize a counter variable
$numSundays = 0;

// Loop through each day of the month
for ($i = $firstDay; $i < $lastDay; $i = strtotime("+1 day", $i)) {
  // Get the day of the week for the current day
  $dayOfWeek = date("l", $i);

  // If the day is Sunday, increment the counter
  if ($dayOfWeek == "Sunday") {
    $numSundays++;
  }
}

// Print the number of Sundays
echo "Number of Sundays: $numSundays\n";

?>
```