# How to find 2nd and 4th Saturday in js Fullcalender?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How I can find second and fourth Saturday in JavaScript fullcalender api, so that I can highlight those 2nd and 4th Saturday with "week Day Off" event name?

Fullcalendar_screenshot[image]

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You asked this before on a question which now seems to be deleted. I commented there and the idea is still the same again - you can create a recurrence rule using rrule - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin, this can create recurring events to populate on the exact schedule you want, for as long as you want. You need to be using fullCalendar 4 or above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find all saturdays in current month. Then filter by odd index since 2th and 4th are `1` and `3` indexes.

Now you can highlight day that matched.

```js
function getSaturdays(year, month) {

            let day, date;
            let saturdays = [];
            day = 1;
            date = new Date(year, month, day);
            while (date.getMonth() === month) {
                if (date.getDay() === 6) { // Sun=0, Mon=1, Tue=2, etc.
                    saturdays.push(new Date(year, month, day).getDate());
                }
                day += 1;
                date = new Date(year, month, day);
            }
            return saturdays;
        }

        let saturdays = getSaturdays(2021, 5).filter((day, index) => index % 2 !== 0)
        console.log(saturdays)
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107520/10984284)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Here instead of arrayOfDaysInMonth variable you can pass javascript dates according to month here i have passed statically 


    

var arrayOfDaysInMonth = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28];//feb

var saturdays = [2,4] // 2nd and 4th saturday;

var secondWeekOfCount = [];
var whichDateIsSecondorFourthSat=[];

arrayOfDaysInMonth.map((i)=>{
    
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(2022);
    myDate.setMonth(1); // Feb
    myDate.setDate(i);

   if(myDate.getDay() === 6){
   secondWeekOfCount.push(i);

     saturdays.map((d)=>{
    if(d ===secondWeekOfCount.length ){
       whichDateIsSecondorFourthSat.push(i)
    }
})


}
})




console.log(whichDateIsSecondorFourthSat)// This will be your result
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it