# How to get the public holidays of each year using Laravel/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, date

I'm beginner in web programming, and now I'm trying to get the number of days between two dates excluding the weekends and the public holidays of each year of our country.
I want to get a list of holidays of my own specific year. Like I pass the year 2021, then it will return all the holidays of 2021, similarly, if I pass 2022, then it will return 2022.

By using the JavaScript, I calculated the difference between two dates excluding the weekends.

The following code describes the difference between two dates excluding the weekends.

```
    function getBusinessDateCount (startDate, endDate) {
       var elapsed, daysBeforeFirstSaturday, daysAfterLastSunday; 
       var ifThen = function (a, b, c) { 
           return a == b ? c : a;
        };
    
    elapsed = endDate - startDate; elapsed /= 86400000;
    
    daysBeforeFirstSunday = (7 - startDate.getDay()) % 7; daysAfterLastSunday = endDate.getDay();
    
    elapsed -= (daysBeforeFirstSunday + daysAfterLastSunday);

    elapsed = (elapsed / 7) * 5; 
    
    elapsed += ifThen(daysBeforeFirstSunday - 1, -1, 0) + ifThen(daysAfterLastSunday, 6, 5);
    
    return Math.ceil(elapsed); }
    
       $(document).ready(function(){    
          $(document).on('change','#date2',function (evt) { 
             let start = document.querySelector('#date1').value, 
             end = document.querySelector('#date2').value,
             result = getBusinessDateCount(new Date(start), 
             new Date(end));  
             document.getElementById("days").value = result+ " Jours";
    
        }); });
```

Now, I'm stuck in how I can add also the public holidays of each year of our country and get the number between two dates excluding weekends and public holidays.

If you have any ideas, please help

Comment: There's no built-in way to get public holidays by country. You might need to find a third party library or implement them yourself. For example for the UK bank holidays are listed [here](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays). There is a general rule of thumb on how you can calculate them but every year they might move one for whatever reason or may add more due to other events e.g. when they added one last year for the queens funeral. For some countries there's not even an agreed upon list of public holidays and it can vary by region

Comment: In some countries, like Switzerland, the public holidays vary also between regions. I think the better approach would be creating a system settings page, where the admins can define their desired public holidays per year...
And if you really want to, you could use some third party libraries to prefill the years.

Answer (score 0):

You have date1 and date2. date1 was in year1 and date2 was in year2.

**year2 >= year1**

Even though it's possible that some holidays are not celebrated every year or, they were introduced between your two dates, for the sake of simplicity I will assume that any holiday is celebrated each year.

So, assuming there are **n** holidays celebrated yearly, you also know that for

**year1 < y < year2**

years, there are **n** holidays. So:

```
let holidays = 0;
if (year2 > year1 + 2) {
    holidays = (year2 - year1 - 1) * n;
}
```

Now, you will need to loop your holidays and compare their months and date against the months and date of `date1` and `date2`, so, if they are later than `date1` then add them and if they are earlier than `date2` then add them (if both criterias are fulfilled, add them twice):

```
let month1 = date1.getMonth();
let day1 = date1.getDate();
let month2 = date2.getMonth();
let day2 = date2.getDate();
for (let holiday of holidayArray) {
    let m = holiday.getMonth();
    let d = holiday.getDate();
    if ((month1 < m) || ((month1 === m) && (day1 <= d))) {
        holidays++;
    }
    if ((month2 > m) || ((month2 === m) && (day2 >= d))) {
        holidays++;
    }
}
```

Now, let's focus on the weekends, luckily this part was already solved at SO at [How to determine number Saturdays and Sundays comes between two dates in java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210906/how-to-determine-number-saturdays-and-sundays-comes-between-two-dates-in-java-sc)

```
function countWeekendDays( d0, d1 )
{
  var ndays = 1 + Math.round((d1.getTime()-d0.getTime())/(24*3600*1000));
  var nsaturdays = Math.floor( (d0.getDay()+ndays) / 7 );
  return 2*nsaturdays + (d0.getDay()==0) - (d1.getDay()==6);
}
```

At the result of `countWeekendDays` to `holidays` and that should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, but how can I extract the holiday days ?

Comment: @rajah That's something you will need to look into and it largely depends on your country's laws. If there is a list of holidays somewhere, then you can create a collection from those. You will need to perform this research, as searching for offsite resources is off-topic at stackoverflow.com. I would not assume there is a resource that you can readily find, but given the fact that there are only 365 days, from which maybe 20-30 are holidays, it should not be a big problem to entry that data. Yet, an issue we did not discuss earlier is the overlap of holidays and weekends.

Comment: @rajah you can add a loop to your program that will loop each year for each holiday for each year in your interval and check whether it's in your interval (in the case of start year/end year) and count the number of holidays that happened to be weekends. Subtract this count from your earlier result.